# US keyboard layout not selectable

Tags: windows-8

If you look at the screenshot you can see that US is installed, but for some reason I cant select it down in the language toolbar (Alt + Shift)

[image]

Comment: That image doesn’t work for me, have you removed the keyboard and re-installed it?

Comment: No idea why you cant see the image but try this one http://www.gratisimage.dk/graphic/images/2013/March/20/9E29_5149C530.jpg I havent changed anything, but I just cant select US layout while I have US, UK and Danish installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by installing a language pack in another language, then deleting US completely and reinstalling it afterwards, then it was selectable.